# Core Data reporting old values?

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

So I'm using MagicalRecord in my iOS application and running into a very bizarre issue. I'm using the following call:

```
[MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
/* look up object in localContext and change property value */ }];
```

and later on retrieving that new value (both on the main thread) using

```
[ObjectName MR_findAll].
```

However, about 1/3 of the time, it is reporting the old value! It is as if Core Data is caching the old version in memory somewhere and I "sometimes" get it and other times don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `MagicalRecord` caches other `MOCs` for different threads and those child `MOCs` were not getting updated even though the parent `MOC` was saving.

So in 
    `NSManagedObjectContext` (MagicalThreading) change this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *threadDict = [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary];
NSManagedObjectContext *threadContext = [threadDict objectForKey:kMagicalRecordManagedObjectContextKey];

if (threadContext == nil)
{
  threadContext = [self MR_contextWithParent:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
  [threadDict setObject:threadContext forKey:kMagicalRecordManagedObjectContextKey];
}
return threadContext;
```

To this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *threadDict = [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary];
NSManagedObjectContext *threadContext = [threadDict objectForKey:kMagicalRecordManagedObjectContextKey];
threadContext = [self MR_contextWithParent:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
[threadDict setObject:threadContext forKey:kMagicalRecordManagedObjectContextKey];

return threadContext;
```

Now as to why the child contexts are not getting updated, I have no idea. But once I did that, everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a forked method not in the primary repo. As such, I can't guarantee that method will even work. Most likely it's a threading issue you're seeing, which is why the contextForCurrentThread methods have been deprecated.

You may have better luck using a method like

```
[localContext saveToPersistentStoreAndWait:^{ /* called after save */ }];
```

or

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){ /* make your changes here*/}];
```

Comment: I had actually tried both of those before as well. Turned out to be some parent/child context issues.